# how to put comma separated words into array

Tags: php, arrays, explode, implode

I have an array which i have converted into comma separated here is how I did it:

```
$array[] = $imp;
$strings = implode(", ", $array);
```

After implode I get 34, 56, 78.

Now I have an array stored in session and I want to add `$strings` into it like:

```
array_push($_SESSION['array'],$strings);
```

But when printed I get:

```
Array ( [0] => 191 [2] => 34, 56, 78 )
```

I want to add 34, 56, 78 value separately so that array can look like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 191 [2] => 34 [3] => 56 [4] => 78 )
```

Comment: Why did you implode the array if you want an array?

Comment: `$_SESSION['array'] = array_merge($_SESSION['array'], $array);`

Comment: because that array is from another php file and through ajax it was little difficult to process

Comment: `json_decode` maybe.  Maybe start the question with the JSON.

Comment: What was difficult to process? You have $array. Isn't that what you need?

Comment: because i have to show that array into input value that doesn't look good that's why!

Comment: So do the merge first then implode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy-paste next code and run in your browser :

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
<?php
$_SESSION[ "arr" ] = array( "100","200","300" );
$strings = "34,56,78";
$_SESSION[ "arr" ] = array_merge( $_SESSION[ "arr" ],explode( ",",$strings) );
var_dump( $_SESSION[ "arr" ] );
?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why explode?  Just don't implode.

Comment: The string `"34,56,78"` is generated using `implode()`

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez Then your answer is unrelated to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Why did you implode the array if you want an array?  Just do this:

```
$_SESSION['array'] = array_merge($_SESSION['array'], $imp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution for you.

```
<?php
$arr= array('5','10,20,30');
$newArr = [];
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {    
    $element = explode(',',$value);
    if (count($element)>1) {
      echo "This is an array";
      foreach ($element as $key => $value1) {
        $newArr[]=$value1;
      }   
    } else {
      echo "Not an array";
      $newArr[]=$value;
    }
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($newArr);

?>
```